# SELECT statement with where clause IN is not reading variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm running SELECT statement (database MySQL version 5.5.27 under Windows 7) with variable in WHERE clause. It supposed to return 6 records, but it doesn't. Below is a simple test code.

```
-- Test-I
SET @group_saids := (SELECT REPLACE(
                                    '''ClicPlan - España|ClicPlan - Francia|ClicPlan - UK|ClicPlan - Belgique|ClicPlan - Argentina|Clicplan - Turkey'''
                                    ,'|',"','") as aids_list from dual);

select @group_saids from dual;


select sd.aid
FROM said_aid sd
where sd.said in (@group_saids);
```

-- No records selected;

-- Test-II

```
select sd.aid
FROM said_aid sd
where sd.said in ('ClicPlan - España','ClicPlan - Francia','ClicPlan - UK',
                  'ClicPlan - Belgique','ClicPlan - Argentina',
                  'Clicplan - Turkey');

aid
----
3045
3253
3254
3260
3268
3270
```

In the code above Test-I, select from table said_aid doesn't return records, but should be 6 records output.
Int the Test-II same query with hard coded IN values return 6 records output.
No ERRORS during execution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) , because the `IN` clause expects literal values, so it won't work with the values inside a string variable, so replace your following line:

```
where sd.said in (@group_saids);
```

for this one:

```
where FIND_IN_SET(sd.said, @group_saids);
```

Comment: Thank you @Nelson, but its still not gives a result... Is any other option?

Comment: never mind - I found. As soon as I removed single quotes (just replace pipes with coma) - it's working fine.